# git old version file cover new version file

Tags: git, cover

I have a partner working with me, my workstation is Linux and my partner's workstation is Windows. We write codes in different module, but sometimes my new updated file maybe cover by his older version file. I'm sure that he didn't modify  my file.

For example:

1. I commit a file  `t1.txt` and merge to master at 9:00 AM;
2. He checkout a branch from master at 9:05 AM;
3. I update file `t1.txt` and merge to master at 10:00 AM;
4. He add a file `t2.txt` and merge his branch ad 10:30 AM, but the old version `t1.txt` (step 1) will convert my newer version (step 3).

What's the problem?

Comment: Have either of you pulled?

Comment: Yes, both of us pulled. But why no modified file would be commited?

Comment: What does `git log --graph --oneline --decorate` show for both of you? Do both of your histories line up?

Comment: What you describe sounds like your partner _didn't_ pull after **3**, and then did something along the lines of a `push -f` (not a merge) after **4**. @Makoto is right: You need to look at the history because actual merges won't result in this situation. Of course after I say this I'm assuming you're talking about in a central repository: If you're talking about the state of _his_ repository than the issue is just that he didn't `pull` **3**.

Comment: The problem is My partner did not pull on his working branch, but on the local master branch.